# how to get executing procedure name in snowflake in sql way

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I get the name of a stored procedure from within that procedure while it is executing. the procedure is written in language sql (not javascript).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test()
returns VARCHAR
language sql
execute as owner
AS
begin

....soemthing like object_name(@@procid) from ms sql server to get "sp_test" as name......

  commit;
end;
```

Comment: This might help https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-procedures.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SHOW TRANSACTIONS`. See [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-transactions.html)

If a `procedure_A` is running in a transaction, and it calls `procedure_B`, and then `procedure_B` runs a query, Then the transactions output of this query should show all three levels of queries as active transactions.

Comment: Thanks David. I was hoping to find something similar to SQL server object_name(@@procid) from within the snowflake scripting stored procedure. I see that if I am to use javascript-based procedure then it would allow me to do this by using object.keys feature. But was more looking from sql side.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood the question, I'm not aware of a query like that. I could certainly see how that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

is there a way to do this now to get procedure name within that SQL scripting procedure in snowflake. I was hoping there will be something like system$current_proc_name will be out there that can be called to get current proc name